# Common Lisp Macro That Times Execution of Forms Inside a Call

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I currently have a need to write something similar to `user::time`, but with a modification.

The modification is the following. Suppose my new macro is called `time-lisp-forms`. Then I should be able to use it like this.

```
(defun test (a b)
  (let ((c (+a b)))
    (time (+ c a))
    (time (+ c b)))))
```

I call the macro like this:

```
(time-lisp-forms (test 1 2))
```

Then, its output would be something like this:

```
Total time for (test 1 2) = 5 sec
Time block 1: (+ c a) = 1 sec
Time block 2: (+ c b) = 3 sec
```

That is, I would like to time the outer call to a function while being able to indicate blocks inside it on which I would like to focus in particular.

The question is whether something like this already exists. Also, if I need to implement this, would you recommend where to begin or some useful functions/macros for this. Not necessarily looking for a working solution, but direction and guidance are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(time-lisp-forms (test 1 2))
```

Could expand as:

```
(let ((*counter* (make-counter :forms '((test 1 2)))))
  (test 1 2)
  (print-summary *counter*))
```

(or expand as a call to a function which does the same).

You dynamically bind a `*counter*` variable to an instance of a `counter` class.

Your custom `(time expr)` expression would expand as:

```
`(call-time-block *counter* ',expr (lambda () ,expr))
```

The function would then give a new id (1, 2, etc.) to the test, and measure time with an internal before/after counter obtained with [`GET-INTERNAL-RUN-TIME`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/f_get__1.htm).

Comment: Are you suggesting that I have two macros in this case? One for outer call and one for inner blocks?

Comment: Yes, only to simplify the syntax for what is otherwise already possible with higher-order functions.